# timer long period time from textview

Tags: android, timer

```
myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }, 0, 3000);
```

I need to change 3000 timer period to take value from `TextView`  `getText()` method.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

> **[As per doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))** :  The third parameter is type **long**. And from textview you will get string. so you need to convert it to type **long**.

**[For more about timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer)**

**Try :**

```
long num = Long.parseLong(textView.getText().toString());

myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }, 0, num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are...

```
long timer = Long.parseLong(textView.getText().toString());

myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        }, 0, timer);
```

EDIT: its a long, not int... other answer was what made me correct mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
EditText edit; 
long timer = Long.parseLong(edit.getText().toString());
```

Comment: he wanted a testview, not editview. but same concept.

Comment: OK change the EditText replace TextView

Comment: why its working definitely check ur id all code ones